# Can I deploy NodeJS Web API to Microsoft IIS?

Tags: node.js, iis, deployment, webapi, nodejs-server

I have a problem, because I created NODEJS API and I have to deploy it on Microsoft IIS. I have never done this before. Is it possible to do? If yes, I will be very grateful if someone describes how to do this.

Comment: Did you read this: https://github.com/Azure/iisnode

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with it. I preferred not to use IISnode, but now I see it's developed by Microsoft and it has any documentation, so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host node.js application, you should firstly install the node.exe and the a build of iisnode.

https://nodejs.org/en/#download

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

After installed the IIS nodes, you could set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call `%programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat`.

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Answer (score -3):

I don't think if that will help you but usually NodeJS don't need a server to be live unlike php or .NET  so you can create a server on NodeJS itself and launched very easy .
also IIS used for statics content and .NET websites about 90% .